# How can I install devDependencies of one of my devDependency?

Tags: node.js, npm, dependency-management, yarnpkg-v2

In a Node project, I want to install all devDependencies of one devDependency of my project.

By default NPM/Yarn will install only the dependencies of my dependencies, but not the devDependencies.

Is there a way to install all devDependencies of a particular devDependency?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended doing is using a `postinstall` script in `package.json`:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "cd node_modules/the-package-i-want-all-dependencies-installed && yarn",
  },
```

This has a big problem though. When someone installs my package it will also run the `postinstall` script, which I don't want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a `prestart` script:

```json
"scripts": {
  "prestart": "cd node_modules/the-package-i-want-all-dependencies-installed && yarn",
},
```

This will not be run when someone installs your package, but one drawback is that it will run every time you run the `start` script.

Answer (score -1):

```
yarn add -D <package...>
```

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/add/#toc-yarn-add-dev-d